# Error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0 Azure DevOps CI Pipline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to Azure DevOps, I am trying to move the development environment to Azure develops and build the CI pipeline as follows:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

This the default pipeline script suggested by the Azure platform.

This is the error sent to the email :

```
4 error(s), 8 warning(s)
    EServices\web.config(68,0): Error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
    ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error 1003: The directory 'D:\a\1\s\ulsa_1\' doesn't exist.
    Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

[Azure DevOps pipeline build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajzMf.png)

I am using visual studio 2017 community edition
Telerik 2019 Q3
Crystal Reports 13.0.2000

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this question is that the Crystal Report is not installed in the Microsoft-hosted agent. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) for information about softwares installed in the Microsoft-hosted agent.

To solve this question, you can:

1. Use self-hosted agent. This method is relatively simple, you can use a machine with Crystal Report installed as an agent to run your pipelines. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#permissions) for detailed information about how to set a self-hosted agent.
2. Add Crystal Report related dlls to your repository manually. In this method, you need to create a new folder in your repository and add `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` dll in it. Then, you need to edit the `Reference` to change the path to the relative path in the repository of the dll.

Comment: I have a similar issue; in that I'm getting the same error. I tried adding NuGet packages for CrystalDecisions.Shared and CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, but they didn't work. In my case I'm using TFS 2015 on-prem. How do I get those 2 packages onto our TFS Build server?